# Duda concepto suma de elementos de una matriz con parámetro tipo puntero

Tags: c++

tengo una duda respecto a este código:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
int Sumar(int* matrix);
int suma;
int main(){

int matrix[5][8] = { { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },{ 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1 },{ 
 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1 },{ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },{ 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
 0 
} };

 for(int i = 0;i<5;i++){

Sumar(matrix[i]);
cout <<suma<<endl;

 }
return 0;

}

int Sumar(int* matrix){


for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
{
    suma = matrix[j] + matrix[j+1];
}


return suma;

}
```

Al ejecutarlo me dan valores incorrectos respecto a lo que debería valer la variable suma, ya se que será un error de concepto por que no logro entender bien los punteros en las funciones.
Me podrían explicar que está fallando?
Muchas gracias.

Comment: podrias poner, que esperas recibir, y que estas recibiendo? gracias!

Comment: Sera que ocupas una misma variable para todas las filas y no la restableces a 0 luego de cada suma de fila?

Comment: Básicamente quiero recibir la suma de los elementos de la matriz, por ejemplo en la primera fila saldría 0 porque es la suma, en la segunda fila saldría 4, y así...

Comment: y que sale? completa la pregunta con eso por favor

Comment: y si.. hay un error de concepto. si vos sumas j + (j+1), en algun punto vas a sumar algo que esta afuera de esa fila

Comment: 1  2  2  2  4 eso es lo que me sale en la consola

Comment: Para futuras preguntas, por favor, edita la pregunta en vez de responder vía comentarios... si esperas que alguien tenga que leerse los comentarios para responderte bajará muchísimo el nivel de las respuestas que recibas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hay varios problemas en tu codigo:

a) No estás recogiendo el valor de retorno de la función Sumar. Usar una variable global (encima sin inicializar) para devolver el valor de una función es bastante peligroso, y deberías evitar este tipo de prácticas. Yo metería suma dentro de main, y crearía una local en Sumar.

```
Sumar(matrix[i]);
cout <<suma<<endl;
```

debería ser algo como:

```
suma = Sumar(matrix[i]);
cout <<suma<<endl;
```

b) Estás sobrepasando los limites de la matriz sobre la que iteras. En el siguiente código:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
{
    suma = matrix[j] + matrix[j+1];
}
```

Tu variable j llega a valer 7, que en j+1 es 8. Al declarar el array de tamaño 8, el indice máximo es 7.

c) En ese mismo bucle, estas sobreescribiendo el valor de la suma en cada iteración, en lugar de añadirlo. Algo así funcionaría mejor:

```
suma = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
{
    suma += matrix[j];
}
```

d) Si quitamos esa variable global tan fea, tenemos que recoger el valor de retorno de Sumar.

```
suma = 0;
for(int i = 0;i<5;i++){
suma += Sumar(matrix[i]);
}
cout << suma << endl;
```

Junta todo esto y debería funcionar. Podrías intentar escribirlo usando tipos de datos estandar del std (como vector o list) y así podrías incluir en la función la gestión automatica de los tamaños de la matriz, y quitar tanto tamaño hardcoded.

Answer (score 2):

[Rhadamon](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/140715/2742) ha dado en el clavo con su respuesta, pero me gustaría añadir una respuesta igual de válida pero con código más moderno.

Iterar un bucle de manera *manual* es propenso a errores como el que ya has experimentado de leer fuera del ámbito de la formación<sup>1</sup>, si realmente quieres usar el bucle te aconsejo usar el bucle `for` de rango, que evita estas situaciones:

```
int suma = 0;

for (const auto &fila : matrix)
    for (const auto &valor : fila)
        suma += valor;
```

El código anterior deduce los límites de la formación<sup>1</sup> de manera que no los tienes que escribir explícitamente, esto además de evitar errores hace que el código se adapte automáticamente si cambias el tamaño de tu `matrix`.

En mi caso, yo omitiría el segundo bucle y delegaría la suma en la cabecera [`<numeric>`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric). La función [`std::accumulate`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) es la que nos sumaría valores dentro de un rango, podríamos usarla así:

```
int suma = 0;

for (const auto &fila : matrix)
    suma = std::accumulate(std::begin(fila), std::end(fila), suma);
```

Pero podemos ir un paso más allá y hacer la función aún más genérica con una plantilla y averiguando el rango de la formación con [`std::rank`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/rank) de la cabecera de características de tipos [`<type_traits>`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits):

```
template <typename T, typename M>
T suma_matrix(const M &m)
{
    T resultado{};

    if constexpr (std::rank_v<M> == 1)
        resultado = std::accumulate(std::begin(m), std::end(m), resultado);
    else
        for (auto &v : m)
            resultado += suma_matrix<T>(v);

    return resultado;
}
```

La plantilla anterior suma todos los valores de una matriz de rango y tamaños arbitrarios, se podría usar así:

```
int m58[5][8] =  {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                  {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1},
                  {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1},
                  {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                  {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}};

int m524[5][2][4] = {{{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}},
                     {{1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1}},
                     {{1, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 1}},
                     {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}},
                     {{1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0}}};

int m5222[5][2][2][2] = {{{{0, 0}, {0, 0}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}},
                         {{{1, 0}, {1, 0}}, {{0, 0}, {1, 1}}},
                         {{{1, 1}, {0, 1}}, {{0, 0}, {1, 1}}},
                         {{{1, 1}, {1, 1}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 1}}},
                         {{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{0, 0}, {1, 0}}}};

std::cout << suma_matrix<int>(m58) << '\n';
std::cout << suma_matrix<int>(m524) << '\n';
std::cout << suma_matrix<int>(m5222) << '\n';
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Wandbox 三へ( へ՞ਊ ՞)へ ﾊｯﾊｯ](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Nd1XZsNllqserrsQ)</kbd>.

---

1. También conocida como arreglo o en inglés array.

Answer (score 0):

Cambia tu función por esta versión. Lo probe y va sumando OK

```
int Sumar(int* matrix){


for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
{
    suma =suma+ matrix[j]; 
}


return suma;

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código completo que funciona. Es tu código con el cambio en la función

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
int Sumar(int* matrix);
int suma;
int main(){

int matrix[5][8] = { { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },{ 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1 },{ 
 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1 },{ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },{ 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
 0 
} };

 for(int i = 0;i<5;i++){

Sumar(matrix[i]);
cout <<suma<<endl;

 }
return 0;

}

int Sumar(int* matrix){


for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
{
    suma =suma+ matrix[j]; 
}


return suma;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

este seria tu código corregido:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int Sumar(int *matrix);
int suma;
int main() {

  int matrix[5][8] = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                      {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1},
                      {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1},
                      {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                      {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}};

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

    Sumar(matrix[i]);
    cout << suma << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}

int Sumar(int *matrix) {
    suma = 0;
  for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
    suma += matrix[j];
  }

  return suma;
}
```

El problema aquí es que estas haciendo mal la suma, ya que estas sobre pasando la medida de tu vector con el `for` de la `Suma` ya que al ser `matrix[j]+matrix[j+1]` cuando tu vector este en la ultima posición no tendrá una adelante para sumarla.

DE igual forma, cada que estas iterando en `Suma` estas repitiendo valores ya que seria como tener `[1,2,3,4]` y sumaras `1+2` cuando `j=0` después cuando `j=1` sumarias `2+3` estarías repitiendo el numero 2.

Es por eso que en el código que te puse, la mejor forma es por medio de un contador, que va sumándose consigo mismo cada vez que itera.

Comment: Cuidado que suma es una variable global. Yo creo que la solución no funciona, porque en cada llamada a Sumar reinicializas el valor de la suma.

Comment: Si, lo reiniciaba por que no sabia que es lo que quería la persona... si que la sumatoria fuera total o por cada linea de la matriz, en este caso supuse que era de cada una por que lo imprime 1 en 1, de lo contrario solamente seria borrar el `suma = 0;`